# Reading and writing JSON in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I load and work with JSON config file during install time? I can read string from file and write it, but if I want to change some value in config file, I have to use `VBScript.RegExp` COM object (which is good, but painful and slow to develop).

Current method:

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile('config.json');
filename := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\config.json');
LoadStringFromFile(filename, conf);

objRegExp := CreateOleObject('VBScript.RegExp');
objRegExp.Pattern := 'test';
conf := objRegExp.Replace(conf, 'test_replace');
SaveStringToFile(filenameOut, conf, False);
```

Is there a better way to do this? All I need is to replace some values in JSON object, no extra magic.

Comment: [TLama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351838/9380811) works, but requires the JSON file to be minified.

Comment: See also [Inno Setup: How can I edit and retrieve value from a children section of a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55520447/850848).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've setup the new project called [`Inno JSON Config`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-json-config/), which allows you to work with simple JSON config files like shown below and which allows you to read and write string, integer and boolean values:

```json
{
    "Section_1":{
            "Key_1": "String 1",
            "Key_2": "1",
            "Key_3": "True"
    },
    "Section_2":{
            "Key_1": "String 2",
            "Key_2": "2",
            "Key_3": "False"
    }
}
```

The usage is quite straightforward (even when I'm going to add handle support as well). Note, that only Unicode Inno Setup (in one of the most recent versions due to a required `Int64` support) can be used:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "JSONConfig.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function JSONQueryString(FileName, Section, Key, Default: WideString;
  var Value: WideString; var ValueLength: Integer): Boolean;
  external 'JSONQueryString@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';
function JSONQueryBoolean(FileName, Section, Key: WideString; 
  Default: Boolean; var Value: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'JSONQueryBoolean@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';
function JSONQueryInteger(FileName, Section, Key: WideString; 
  Default: Int64; var Value: Int64): Boolean;
  external 'JSONQueryInteger@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';
function JSONWriteString(FileName, Section, Key, 
  Value: WideString): Boolean;
  external 'JSONWriteString@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';
function JSONWriteBoolean(FileName, Section, Key: WideString;
  Value: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'JSONWriteBoolean@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';
function JSONWriteInteger(FileName, Section, Key: WideString;
  Value: Int64): Boolean;
  external 'JSONWriteInteger@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';

function BoolToStr(Value: Boolean): string;
begin
  Result := 'True';
  if not Value then
    Result := 'False';
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  FileName: WideString;
  IntValue: Int64;
  StrValue: WideString;
  StrLength: Integer;
  BoolValue: Boolean;
begin
  { set the source JSON config file path }
  FileName := 'c:\Example.json';
  { allocate string buffer to enough length }
  SetLength(StrValue, 16);
  { set the buffer length value }
  StrLength := Length(StrValue);
  { query string value }
  if JSONQueryString(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_1', 'Default', StrValue, 
    StrLength)
  then
    MsgBox('Section_1:Key_1=' + StrValue, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  { query integer value }
  if JSONQueryInteger(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_2', 0, IntValue) then
    MsgBox('Section_1:Key_2=' + IntToStr(IntValue), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  { query boolean value }
  if JSONQueryBoolean(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_3', True, BoolValue) then
    MsgBox('Section_1:Key_3=' + BoolToStr(BoolValue), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  { write string }
  if not JSONWriteString(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_1', 'New value!') then
    MsgBox('JSONWriteString Section_1:Key_1 failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
  { write integer }
  if not JSONWriteInteger(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_2', 123) then
    MsgBox('JSONWriteInteger Section_1:Key_2 failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
  { write boolean }
  if not JSONWriteBoolean(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_3', False) then
    MsgBox('JSONWriteBoolean Section_1:Key_3 failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Soon (I hope) will be ready [`Inno JSON Parser`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-json-parser/wiki/Reference). It will use a handle for keeping parsed file opened (it will use a `TInterfaceList` of `ISuperObject` interface references). It will allow more flexible way of working with JSON files. I'll update this post when will be ready. Already tested code is ready to deploy, I just need to finish wiki and add some examples of use. The similar library I'm going to write also for XML format.

Comment: Also JSONQueryString never retrieves the last character

Comment: Indeed, this does not seem to be working anymore. Rather use JsonParser library. See [How to parse a JSON string in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34290115/850848)