# JSON parser extension library for InnoSetup

Tags: json, dll, inno-setup, freepascal

I need to parse a JSON file from InnoSetup Script. Two years ago the user TLama (https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) wrote a library (https://code.google.com/p/inno-json-parser/) for parse JSON, I searched and searched many times but don't found links to download it. Anyone have a copy of this library ?

Linked question: [Inno Setup: Working with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335340/inno-setup-working-with-json)

Comment: No one has a copy. It was not released. You can try inno-json-config, or e.g. [JsonParser](https://github.com/koldev/JsonParser).

Comment: Thanks!!!! I'll try inno-json-config