# Checking all values in JSON object in Inno Setup when parsing response from ipregistry

Tags: json, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to prevent bot installs using ipregistry IP Geolocation and Threat Detection API. But I am getting results in the below format. Can you help me integrating this with Inno Setup to exit the installer, if any of the below is `true`?

API URL https://api.ipregistry.co/50.75.90.218?key=roygrcxz372rjb&fields=security

API result

```json
{
    "security": {
        "is_bogon": false,
        "is_cloud_provider": false,
        "is_tor": false,
        "is_tor_exit": false,
        "is_proxy": false,
        "is_anonymous": false,
        "is_abuser": false,
        "is_attacker": false,
        "is_threat": false
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to call the online API:
[Check an IP address against an online list in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62330068/850848)

You basically already know even how to parse the JSON, but ok, this is bit specific. With use of [JsonParser library](https://github.com/koldev/JsonParser) and my functions from [How to parse a JSON string in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34290115/850848), you can write:

```pascal
function AllowInstallation(Json: string): Boolean;
var
  JsonParser: TJsonParser;
  JsonRoot, SecurityObject: TJsonObject;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  Log('Parsing');
  if not ParseJsonAndLogErrors(JsonParser, Json) then
  begin
    Log('Cannot parse, allowing installation');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Parsed');
    JsonRoot := GetJsonRoot(JsonParser.Output);
    if not FindJsonObject(JsonParser.Output, JsonRoot, 'security', SecurityObject) then
    begin
      Log('Cannot find "security", allowing installation');
    end
      else
    begin
      for I := 0 to Length(SecurityObject) - 1 do
      begin
        if SecurityObject[I].Value.Kind <> JVKWord then
        begin
          Log(Format('"%s" is not "word", ignoring', [SecurityObject[I].Key]));
        end
          else
        if JsonParser.Output.Words[SecurityObject[I].Value.Index] = JWTrue then
        begin
          Log(Format('"%s" is "true", not allowing the installation', [
            SecurityObject[I].Key]));
          Result := False;
        end
          else
        begin
          Log(Format('"%s" is not "true"', [SecurityObject[I].Key]));
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  ClearJsonParser(JsonParser);
end;
```