# Parsing JSON Boolean value in Inno Setup?

Tags: json, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to parse JSON Boolean value in Inno Setup. I've tried to modify the code from [How to parse a JSON string in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34290115/850848#34291316) to parse Booleans like this:

```pascal
function FindJsonBoolean(
  Output: TJsonParserOutput; Parent: TJsonObject; Key: TJsonString;
  var Bool: TJsonBool): Boolean;
var
  JsonValue: TJsonValue;
begin
  Result :=
    FindJsonValue(Output, Parent, Key, JsonValue) and
    (JsonValue.Kind = JVKBoolean);
  if Result then
    begin    
      Bool := Output.Boolean[JsonValue.Index]; 
    end;
end;
```

But it fails to compile with:

> Unknown type 'TJsonBool'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `TJsonBool` in the [JsonParser library](https://github.com/koldev/JsonParser). There's:

```pascal
TJsonWord = (JWUnknown, JWTrue, JWFalse, JWNull);
```

Use something like this and compare `TheWord` with `JWTrue`/`JWFalse`.

```pascal
function FindJsonWord(
  Output: TJsonParserOutput; Parent: TJsonObject; Key: TJsonString;
  var TheWord: TJsonWord): Boolean;
var
  JsonValue: TJsonValue;
begin
  Result :=
    FindJsonValue(Output, Parent, Key, JsonValue) and
    (JsonValue.Kind = JVKWord);

  if Result then
  begin    
    TheWord := Output.Words[JsonValue.Index]; 
  end;
end;
```